# Memory per user on AIX

Tags: memory-usage, aix, virtual-memory

`nmon` is showing me 99% memory usage and swap activity. My user is not very active at the moment so it should be someone elses fault.

Is there a way I figure how much memory each user is taking?
Must be a non root command. It is an AIX 5 box.

thanks.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.aix/browse_thread/thread/09888834f408ec7a

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure the answer lays there, but I was hoping to not have to learn how to interpret svmons output right now (although it is sure attractive). Wish there was a more straight forward answer.

Comment: AIX will always use as much memory as possible.  99% memory 'in use' isn't an issue as long as it's being used efficiently.  Also, 'swap activity' is meaningless without some quantifier.  Before looking for a solution, make sure you have a problem.  How are you deciding there is swap activity and how much of it is there?

Comment: You are right. I do know AIX tries to keep memory at maximum and that there is always some paging activity. But the problem here is pretty obvious (well, not a _problem_ as it stands, rather high activity situation), and I just want to take a look into it. Not worth it to go into details since this is an rather expected server load, I just want to see it's distribution across the users.

Comment: Then you need to learn to use svmon - for which you'll need to be root (iirc)

Comment: @EightBitTony check my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without being root.  You need to be root, and you use `svmon -U`

You can get some information from `ps`, `topas`, maybe even `nmon`, but not down to the user level.  That's what `svmon` is for.